# how to change view of holder object in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, adapter

I am using adapter with holder for list view.list item contains button.i have to change view of that button using on click listener. SO how can i do this.

```
// holder.bt.setVisibility(holder.bt.GONE);
// holder.cc.setVisibility( holder.cc.VISIBLE);
// v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1) ;
```

Comment: please be clear with your question, Please provide code and scenario

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. 
`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

```
     holder.bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder.bt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.cc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
                holder.v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1);
        }           
    });
```

Comment: i had tryed all these with in onclick lisner inside get view() cant able to fix the issue..

//holder.bt.setVisibility(btGONE);
//   holder.cc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        
// holder.bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1) ;
//  holder.bt.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
//   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star1) ;